# Turning a trigonometric expression into a product

Tags: trigonometry

I was working on a simplistic looking trigonometry problem where I had to turn $1+\cot(a)$ and $1-\cot(a)$, individually into products, so $1+\cot(a)$ would become a product and $1-\cot(a)$ would be another product.

At first I tried turning $\cot(a)$ into $\dfrac{\cos(a)}{\sin(a)}$ and simplified from there, but I only ended up with sums and differences.

I then used trigonometric identities to replace $\cot(a)$ to no avail.

Is there a way to turn $1+\cot(a)$ and $1-\cot(a)$ into products?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  This question isn't clear. What do you mean by "turn it into a product"?  What kind of product?  Is $1-\cot a=2\left(\frac{1-\cot a}{2}\right)$ good enough?  Why not?  Please clarify what you are looking for. Also, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows
$$1\pm\cot a$$
$$=1\pm\frac{\cos a}{\sin a}$$
$$=\frac{\sin a\pm \cos a}{\sin a}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt2\sin \left(a\pm \frac{\pi}{4}\right)}{\sin a}$$
$$=\sqrt2\sin \left(a\pm \frac{\pi}{4}\right)cosec a$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Using the addition formulæ, it is standard to rewrite

- $\sin a+\cos a=\sqrt 2\sin\bigl(a+\frac\pi4\bigr)$
- $\sin a-\cos a=\sqrt 2\sin\bigl(a-\frac\pi4\bigr)$